# What are different types of ways to create to a GUI in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

As far as I know, we can create GUI using:

- xml
- opengles

so is there any other way to create GUI in android?

-Thanks

Comment: It is look like very strange question. What will you do with this gui. You need to have business layer (model) and so on... Maybe you need to look on different firework like xamarin e.t.c

Comment: You can also use Java code. But your best bet is using XML layouts.

Comment: stfd thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make views using java.  Either by creating views manually or by using a library such as anvil https://github.com/zserge/anvil